# spark window function missing values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

i have a dataframe

```
+------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
|devId |servertimestamp|trackingnumber|   servertimestamp2|
+------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
|  8010|     1602022571|  480027192318|2020-10-06 22:16:11|
|  8010|     1602022572|  116035246092|2020-10-06 22:16:12|
|  8010|     1602022573|  495863861847|2020-10-06 22:16:13|
|  8010|     1602022575|  485108185153|2020-10-06 22:16:15|
|  8010|     1602022576|  787294899718|2020-10-06 22:16:16|
|  8010|     1602022577|  118929636841|2020-10-06 22:16:17|
|  8010|     1602022579|  119867330791|2020-10-06 22:16:19|
|  8010|     1602022580|  118929640260|2020-10-06 22:16:20|
|  8010|     1602022581|  114194932911|2020-10-06 22:16:21|
|  8010|     1602022583|  104499502413|2020-10-06 22:16:23|
|  8010|     1602022584|  104499503350|2020-10-06 22:16:24|
|  8010|     1602022585|  789385310169|2020-10-06 22:16:25|
|  8010|     1602022587|  789385066288|2020-10-06 22:16:27|
|  8010|     1602022588|  113194381766|2020-10-06 22:16:28|
|  8010|     1602022589|  119846967190|2020-10-06 22:16:29|
|  8010|     1602022591|  114478769341|2020-10-06 22:16:31|
|  8010|     1602022593|  114478769352|2020-10-06 22:16:33|
|  8010|     1602022594|  776077921980|2020-10-06 22:16:34|
|  8010|     1602022596|  116088883660|2020-10-06 22:16:36|
|  8010|     1602022597|  414142833630|2020-10-06 22:16:37|
+------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

i want to get count of records for each devId for every 5 minutes windows. So i do

```
  val myDF2 = myDF.groupBy(col("devId"), window(col("servertimestamp2"), "5 minutes", "5 minutes")).count()
```

testing results:

```
myDF2.select("*").where("devId = 3121").orderBy("window").show(false)
```

result i get has gaps. for example there is no data for time window 17:35:00 -- 17:40:00, 18:00:00 -- 18:55:00. I assume that is because there were no records in those time periods.
How do i make it show all time windows, even those with 0 count?

```
 +------+------------------------------------------+-----+
    |devId |window                                    |count|
    +------+------------------------------------------+-----+
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 17:30:00, 2020-10-06 17:35:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 17:40:00, 2020-10-06 17:45:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 17:45:00, 2020-10-06 17:50:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 17:50:00, 2020-10-06 17:55:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 17:55:00, 2020-10-06 18:00:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 18:55:00, 2020-10-06 19:00:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 21:10:00, 2020-10-06 21:15:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-06 21:20:00, 2020-10-06 21:25:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 00:45:00, 2020-10-07 00:50:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:10:00, 2020-10-07 01:15:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:15:00, 2020-10-07 01:20:00]|2    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:20:00, 2020-10-07 01:25:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:25:00, 2020-10-07 01:30:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:35:00, 2020-10-07 01:40:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:50:00, 2020-10-07 01:55:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 01:55:00, 2020-10-07 02:00:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 02:10:00, 2020-10-07 02:15:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 05:40:00, 2020-10-07 05:45:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 05:45:00, 2020-10-07 05:50:00]|1    |
    |3121  |[2020-10-07 05:50:00, 2020-10-07 05:55:00]|1    |
    +------+------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Wrong sample data.

Comment: can you verify you had no data in those periods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to generate a second dataframe containing all possible combinations of time windows and devIds and then join this dataframe with `myDF2` to fill the gaps.

```scala
//get the minimal and maximal timestamps of all windows
//myDF2 should be cached before this operation
val minMax = myDF2.agg("window"->"min", "window" -> "max").collect()(0)
val (min, max) = (minMax.getStruct(0).getTimestamp(0),
                  minMax.getStruct(1).getTimestamp(1))

//get the distinct devIds from the original data
val devIds = myDF.select('devId).distinct()

//create the sequence of all possible windows and cross join it with the devIds
//the cross join should not be too slow because at least the list of windows
//should always be small enough to be broadcasted
val dft = spark.sql(s"select explode(sequence(to_timestamp('$min', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'), to_timestamp('$max', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'), interval 5 minutes)) as Date")
    .groupBy( window(col("Date"), "5 minutes")).count().drop("count")
    .crossJoin(devIds)

//join the second dataframe to myDF2
myDF2.join(dft, Seq("devId","window"), "right")
  .orderBy("devId", "window")
  .select("devId", "window", "count").show(false)
```

Comment: The standard way.